# Xindy fails to sort umlauts in Imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, xindy

I'm using Imakeidx to auto-generate an author index for my bibentries, but I have a problem with the sorting of some special characters such as umlauts. As suggested, I tried to use xindy as a engine for the sorting, but the only result I got is that I have to process also the .idx file (without xindy I didn't need to), but the sorting is still wrong.

In my example, I need first Döllinger and then Dull.

I'm dying on it, really.

MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@book{Dull,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {Mark Dull},
    Publisher = {Amazon KDP},
    Title = {Hello world},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{Dol2,
    Address = {Moskwa},
    Author = {Philip Döllinger},
    Publisher = {Sinodal'naja tip.},
    Title = {Sistematičeskoe opisanie rukopisej moskovskoj Sinodal'noj (patriaršej) biblioteki},
    Year = {1894}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=true,
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=xindy, name=nomi, intoc=true, title=Indice dei nomi]

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\ifnameundef{namea}{\indexnames{labelname}}{\indexnames{namea}}}
    {}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%      Formato del nome dell'autore
  \usebibmacro{index:name}
    {\index[nomi]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}


\begin{document}


I should like to sort properly \cite{Dull} and \cite{Dol2}.



\printindex[nomi]       % Indice dei nomi   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this is at least somewhat related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426811/35864 As I mentioned in my comment under that question it would be good to know which exact sorting rules/algorithm you intend to follow, not just the outcome of your MWE

Comment: simply alphabetic, ignoring the umlauts at all

Comment: I'm also open to any other possible solution for an automated author name index that runs the sorting properly

Comment: How do you compile your document? Do you actually run `xindy`? (I use `latexmk` and that did not run `xindy` automatically for me. I had to enable shell escape as mentioned in the `imakeidx` manual).

Comment: Do you actually have a latexmkrc file that defines makeindex as xindy with the proper encoding?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and I use Texshop. ATM I'm running XeLaTeX - Biber - XeLaTeX, but with xindy I have to run also the .idx with makeindex (I do it with texworks, I don't know how to do it with texshop), I don't know what is a latexmkrc file. Please forgive my ignorance, I'm still a noob on many things!

Comment: You don't have to run the `.idx` with `makeindex` you have to run it with `xindy`! It works if you run `makeindex` and you get an index, but you don't get `xindy`'s features. If you want `xindy` you need to run `xindy`.

Comment: `imakeidx` tries to run `texindy` through the shell escape, but if it can't, it writes the command you need to call in the transcript. In this case `texindy nomi.idx`, but you also need to specify the language as well. For example `texindy -L german-din5007 -C utf8 nomi.idx`. To incorporate it into TeXshop, try [Adding a new engine in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376649/adding-a-new-engine-in-texshop). In this case, you need to explicitly use `nomi.ist` rather than appending `.ist` to the basename.

Comment: It worked running texindy -L german-din5007 -C utf8 nomi.idx. Honestly incorporating xindy in texshop is too difficult (exoteric!) for me. If it doesn't exist any simpler way I'll use this one :) BTW I find rather surprising that LaTeX doesn't have a simple way to automate an author index able to sort names with umlauts or special characters.

Comment: If you run XeLaTeX with shell escape enabled (`latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape`) `xindy` will be run automatically for you. TeX predates Unicode and does not really do non-ASCII-characters in general. The first indexing tools for LaTeX (indexing is best done externally, LaTeX isn't great at sorting strings, see BibTeX) were also not great with non-ASCII. `xindy` is the go-to solution for non-ASCII indices and it seems to work very well, but `latexmk` does not support it out of the box, so you either have to write your own rule, use shell escape or arara.

Comment: An easy solution is to enable shell-escape with the method described by Egreg here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/how-to-customize-the-default-xelatex-command-in-texshop-for-osx and to set xindy with \def\xindylangopt{-M lang/german/din5007-utf8-lang}. Also, the option options=\xindylangopt must be enabled. It worked much better for me.